# read an html url line by line in python

Tags: python, html, string

I want to apply string manipulation for a webpage like I would do with a local normal file line by line like:

```
save = []
ins = open("my_file.html", "r")

for line in ins:
    if "/html/" in line and "thumbs" in line:
        print(line)
```

However when I am trying to take directly a webpage and then converting it to utf-8 then I am no longer able to parse line by line, here is my code:

```
fp = urllib.request.urlopen(base + ".html")
mystr = fp.read()
mystr = mystr.decode("utf-8")

for line in mystr:
    if "/html/" in line and "thumbs" in line:
        print(line)
```

So whats am I doing wrong here, is this the way I decode the page after receiving it, the library I am using, the way I use my string or something else ?

here is the result of `cat my_file.html | head`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-4477008-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
```

Comment: Can you share some of the data of that html file?

Comment: you have to manually split in lines `mystr.split("\n")`.

Comment: as for me manipulation as normal text has no sense. Tag may start in one line and it may end few lines later. It is better to use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to parse it.

Comment: @Poojan updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So whats am I doing wrong here

Iterating over a file object gives you the lines of the file, but iterating over a string gives you the individual characters (as length-1 strings).

You would need to split the string back into lines yourself, e.g. with `.splitlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use BeautifulSoup to complete this task.

Here's an example, loading a local html file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "C:\\my_folder\\my_file.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'example'})

for div in divs:
    print (div)
```